# pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tikz/triangle 60'

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, beamerposter

Here I am back again with a new question.

I try to make a poster with beamerposter. Now I would like to draw a arrow with tikz, but I get this error message `pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tikz/triangle 60'`

Here is the code I am using

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,automata,shapes.arrows}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]

  \begin{columns}[t]

  \begin{column}{.02\textwidth}\end{column}

  \begin{column}{.465\textwidth}


  \begin{block}{TITLE}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-15pt]current bounding box.north)},line width=6pt]
        \draw[->,stealth'](0,0)--(1.2,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{block}

  \end{column}

  \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know why I get this error?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I get another error compiling this document: `pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tikz/stealth'` because `[->,stealth']` it is not the correct way to set the arrow. You will find in the documentation the correct setting.

Comment: Try `\draw[-stealth](0,0)--(1.2,0);` or `\draw[-stealth'](0,0)--(1.2,0);`. This is working for me.

Comment: @ferahfeza It works! So simple and I'm trying to fix this for hours.

Comment: You need a dash in any arrow setting such as `|-|` or `-latex` etc. Without a dash the option is search as a key name.

Comment: #Froop: Could you or @ferahfeza add an answer to close this question? As you said "It works!". - Since you have some responses also to other questions that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)). It's part [of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.